# update excel graph according to new data populated using vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim lastcolumn As Integer
    Dim EndColumnname As String
    Dim StartColumnname As String
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    EndColumnname = ConvertToLetter(lastcolumn)
    StartColumnname = ConvertToLetter(lastcolumn - 4)
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
   'ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1,C1:H1,A3:A4,C3:H4")
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1", StartColumnname & 1 & ":" & EndColumnname & 1, "A3:A4", StartColumnname & 3 & ":" & EndColumnname & 4)
End Sub

Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
   Dim iAlpha As Integer
   Dim iRemainder As Integer
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
End Function
```

i am getting the error in this line

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1", StartColumnname & 1 & ":" & EndColumnname & 1, "A3:A4", StartColumnname & 3 & ":" & EndColumnname & 4)
```

Error is - Compile error--- wrong no. of arguments or invalid property assigned

3rd parameter - is series labels 
2nd parameter - date range for x axis label 
4th parameter - data range

It works fine when i hard code it like

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1,C1:H1,A3:A4,C3:H4")
```

I want when data is populated in "I" column the above line become as shown below with the help of code

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1,D1:I1,A3:A4,D3:I4")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to borrow R3uK's `ConvertToLetter` routine, but you can set your source data in a single line if you'd like, you just have to fix the formatting & concatenation.

Change

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1", StartColumnname & 1 & ":" & _
  EndColumnname & 1, "A3:A4", StartColumnname & 3 & ":" & EndColumnname & 4)
```

to

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1," & StartColumnname & "1:" & _
  EndColumnname & "1, A3:A4," & StartColumnname & "3:" & EndColumnname & "4")
```

You just managed to confuse yourself with location of commas *outside* of quoted strings, when they needed to be inside. For example, in your original line, you have `"A1",`, where the comma outside the quotes is a parameter separator, not a separator between the ranges.

Comment: Glad I could help. Click the check mark so others have an easier time finding a working solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating your life. I personally tend to load my data into a *table* and deploy the chart to given table. When the dataset expands, the table expands as well and your chart will refresh by itself. May not work in your case (shared wb or such) but for me it usually does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create an intermediate string and I changed your ConvertToLetter with something more efficient (I used the same algo before too ;) )

Try this :

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim Wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim LastColumn As Integer
    Dim EndColumnname As String
    Dim StartColumnname As String
    Dim RgSrc1 As String
    Dim RgSrc2 As String


    'Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastColumn = Ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    EndColumnname = ConvertToLetter(LastColumn)
    StartColumnname = ConvertToLetter(LastColumn - 4)


   'ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1,C1:H1,A3:A4,C3:H4")
    RgSrc1 = StartColumnname & 1 & ":" & EndColumnname & 1
    RgSrc2 = StartColumnname & 3 & ":" & EndColumnname & 4

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1", RgSrc1, "A3:A4", RgSrc2)

    Set Wb1 = Nothing
    Set Ws1 = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
With ActiveSheet.Columns(iCol)
    ConvertToLetter = Left(.Address(False, False), InStr(.Address(False, False), ":") - 1)
End With
End Function
```